# Issue with text search using Subject and http client service

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've been developing a text search using keyup and Rxjs Subject

It searches through multiple APIs and returns a single object

All works fine until I clear the text field, at first I got 404 as the app still made the http calls with empty query.

I can suppress the errors by checking if the string is empty, but the app still fails silently, meaning: the app will not update, freezes

I set up the Subject in the SearchComponent and subscribe to the search function in searchService

```
public searchStr = new Subject<string>();

constructor(private searchService: SearchService) {
    this.searchService.search(this.searchStr)
    .subscribe((result)=> {
     this.result = result;
     this.movies = result[0];
     this.games = result[1];
     this.comics = result[2];

    })
   }
```

In the html

```
<input (keyup)="searchStr.next($event.target.value)">
```

The service

The search function that is observed from searchComponent

```
 public search(query: Observable<string>){
    return query.debounceTime(400)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .switchMap(query => this.callSearches(query))
  }
```

It calls a function that uses forkJoin to execute the API calls

```
public callSearches(query){
    return Observable.forkJoin([
        this.searchMovies(query),
        this.searchGames(query),
        this.searchComics(query),
        this.searchMusic(query)
    ])
      .map((data)=>{
        this.searchResults = data;
        return this.searchResults

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return Observable.throw(error)
      })

  }
```

Below is one of the API calls; they're all pretty similar

```
public searchMusic(query): Observable<any>{
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

          return this.http.get(this.url+'/music/search/'+query, options)
             .map((data) => {
             let  result;
                  result = data.json().data.albums.items;
                  return result;
                })
            .catch((error) => {
          return Observable.throw(error)
         })
      }
```

I was wondering how others handle such issues

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "but the app still fails silently, meaning: the app will not update, freezes"? What is the behavior you expect?

Comment: I expect; if I remove all text from the text field, then input new text, it should execute a  new search, but it does nothing, any output to the page from last search remains the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just filter empty queries?

```
public search(query: Observable<string>){
    return query.debounceTime(400)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .filter(query => query.length > 0)
    .switchMap(query => this.callSearches(query))
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

your implementation was good but i would recommend add min character before doing search operation.

I will recommend start searching after enter 3 characters

```
    <input (keyup)="searchStrFun($event.target.value)">

searchStrFun(input){
 if(input.length > 2) {  
        searchStr.next(input)
    }
}
```

Coming to Freezing where it was freezing ? any console.log

Comment: Thanks, maybe freezing was the wrong word to use, basically I get a 404 error, when I clear out the text field, as the calls to the APIs still execute, then the search refuses to work when I re-enter text. I can suppress the errors, if i check if the string is empty at various parts of the code, however the the search still does not work

Comment: my recommendation simple don't do search operation if string is empty. other than that your implementation is good